# How does the Date object update without recompiling the program in Java?

Tags: java, date, instantiation

Example:

```
System.out.println(new Date());
```

Now obviously this is part of a larger program, but you can see what this does. Now, I run the compiler once, and then run the program. Then, without compiling the program again, I run it and the date updates. This might seem stupid but how does the date update without updating the bytecode?

From my understanding through what I have read the Java compiler takes my source code and compiles it to bytecode, which is saved in a class file. The JIT converts this code to machine code and it runs. However, wouldn't the state of the Date object stay the same? It obviously doesn't. I am just confused on how it changes.

Comment: What do you think a *compilation* is?

Comment: `new Date` is evaluated when the code is run, not when it is compiled. Compiling doesn't work out the date and store it in your bytecode. It stores the instructions that include looking up the current date.

Comment: Not going to lie I'm 14 and I'm teaching myself. From my understanding through what I have read the java compiler takes my source code and compiles it to byte code, which is saved in a class file. The JIT converts this code to machine code and it runs. However, wouldn't the state of the date object stay the same? It obviously doesn't I am just confused on how it changes.

Comment: ^^ Ah I see. I guess I just had the wrong idea about when it is evaluated. Thanks!

Comment: As you are learning, if you would like to check the bytecode generated from your example try this in your cmd, after you compiled your class: `C:\Test>javap -c C:\Test\YourCompiledClass.class C:\Test\YourBytecode.bc`

Comment: You shouldn’t use the `Date` class. After years of bad experiences with it, its replacement came out when you were 10: [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Try for example `System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));`. The answer will be the same, though: a new `LocalDate` object will be generated every time you run your program.

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, you should avoid the `Date` class. Especially as a student learning Java, you should only study `Date` as an example of how to *not* design a class, as the design is bloody awful. In contrast, the *java.time* classes replacing `Date` are beautifully designed and a pleasure to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Compile-time versus Run-time

The [Answer by Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53246487/642706) is correct. Objects defined in your code are constructed at [run-time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_(program_lifecycle_phase)), not [compile-time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time).

[Compilation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) is like having an engineer review an architect’s plans for a building, and then writing out more detailed specifications. No building is yet built. We are now thoroughly *ready* to build, but have not actually built anything until “run-time” when the construction crew arrives on site.

In this metaphor, your [source code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) is the architect’s drawings. The engineer’s more detailed specifications is the [bytecode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode)  emitted by the Java compiler. The [JVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) running your app’s bytecode is the construction crew going to work on site.

Another way to think if it:

- Classes are determined at compile-time.
- Objects (instances) are determined at run-time.

## java.time

Also, you should never use the `Date` class. That class and the other legacy date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java are *terrible*, riddled with poor design choices. They were supplanted years ago  by the modern *java.time* classes.

The *java.time* classes use [factory methods](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for instantiating rather than [constructors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) and `new`.

```
Instant.now()  // Capture current moment in UTC. 
OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )  // Capture current moment in UTC. 
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) )  // Capture current moment as seen though the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 )  // A date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
```

Comment: No constant available for Africa/Casablanca ?

Comment: @KorayTugay No, no constants for time zones. Politicians around the world have shown an eagerness to frequently rename and redefine their respective time zone(s). The definitions are [soft-coded](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcoding) by way of a [*tzdata*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) file stored outside the compiled classes to facilitate manual updating. The tzdata file needs updating more often and more urgently than releases of the JVM and its library classes.

Comment: @KorayTugay We have one constant, for UTC, an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds: [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC). Example: `OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )`

Comment: Yeah the only reason I was using the date class was due to the way the book I am reading is teaching classes. A little weird but Core Java is a pretty good book.

Answer (score 2):

A `Date` object initialized with the no-arg constructor will access `System.currTimeMilis()` and use the current timestamp from the machine. In other words, the timestamp isn't "compiled into it", but instead it contains code that accesses the machine's clock and takes the timestamp from there each time the program is run.